# Problem with moving div

Tags: css

When I try to move the div #planet up (I change margin-top from -76px to -86px) my whole site "lifts up".

You can view the page here (and see the problem) http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/cssexam/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a div is a block element, so it stretches from one end to the other. So when you change the top of that particular div, you're changing the tops of all the following divs.

See the trick (an oldie but a goodie) at the bottom of this page http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ (as a for instance) to see how this works and to find out how to duplicate it for yourself.

Comment: **SEE IT WITH YOUR OWN EYES** Wanna see every single "box" that makes up a page? Try putting this in the stylesheet temporarily: `* {    border: 1px solid red !important; }`

Comment: @lam3r4370 notice you would put that as the last CSS rule to be interpreted

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working, and I see what you ended up doing with it too ;) smooth transition

Answer (score 0):

try to add height parameter to "icons" div... when you change that margin now, size of parent div(icons) is affected and whole site moves up because that div changed height

Comment: Ok, but _why_ does this work ;) ~ Make a better answer than the rest

Comment: Just told you, that div doesnt have fixed height and when you chnage it by moving element inside it, the whole page goes up because divs are stacked on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

just apply `padding-top:10px;` for the `#container`

Comment: That wouldn't actually do what he wants.

Comment: @drachenstern if I understood correctly, the content below "lifts up" so he wants to keep it in the same place. Adding `padding-top:10px` then the content returns in it's place.

Comment: But what he wants is for just the planet div by itself to move. Perhaps if he added the padding-top to the `#nav` that might be what he wants, but to #container wouldn't change anything. Try playing with the styles manually yourself on the individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all margin of the class .iconss

Use position:absolute on #icons and set the position:relative in the class .iconss

Now, use top and left css property to set the icon position.

Cleber.

Answer (score 0):

id=icons are above the id=nav. When you edit the top margin of an element in id=icons it effect id=icons. When id=icons goes up the others goes up too. I suggest you to use position css for icons and nav too.